# Custom type parsing issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a type product defined like this :

```
export class Product {
  id: number;
  //other fields
}
```

a variable formattedProducts inside my component :

```
  formattedProducts: Product[] = [];
```

I want to update this variable here:

```
refreshSummary(product: Product): void{
    var found = false;
    for (var p in this.formattedProducts){
        console.log('parsing product summary', p);
        if (p.id == product.id){
          // we update
          console.log('updating product')
          found = true;
          break;
        }
    }
```

My issue is that I have debugger error :

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'
```

which occurs on my "p.id". My variable this.formattedProducts is an array of Product, so I don't know how is it interpreted as a string.
Is it possible to force define a type of my variable p or to make my formattedProduct an array of Product in another way that the one I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `for (var p in this.formattedProducts){` should be `for (var p of this.formattedProducts){`

Currently, you iterating over properties of formattedProducts array object and each `p` is a name of property

Comment: Well done, I ll accept your answer as soon as I can!

Comment: use let or const instead of var.